# check all textfields simultaneously & only enable button if they have text

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, uitextfield

I want to enable and change color of a button depending on text in password and confirm password textfields. So I found this code online:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let tfConfirmPasswordText = (tfConfirmPassword.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
    if tfConfirmPasswordText.isEmpty {
        btnContinue.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "labelColor")
        btnContinue.isEnabled = false
    }
        else if tfPassword.text != "" && !tfConfirmPasswordText.isEmpty {
        btnContinue.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "accentColor")
        btnContinue.isEnabled = true
    }
     return true
    }
```

This code does work and using these conditions it will enable or disable continue button according to `confirmPassword` textfield.
But the problem is that after filling both `password` and `confirmPassword` textfields, if I remove text from `password` field it still keeps the button enabled and only disables it if text is removed from `confirmPassword` textfield.
And if I put `password.delegate = self` alongside `confirmPassword.delgate = self` in `viewDidLoafd()`, it crashes when I put more than 1 character in any textfield.

Is there any way to enable or disable button by always keeping a check on both the textfields instead of just one..ie. confirmPassword textfield?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using shouldChangeCharactersIn ,i used like below to make it works

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
          //initially at disabled 
            disabledButton()
            [tfPassword, tfConfirmPasswordText].forEach({ $0.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldEditingDidChange), for: .editingChanged) })
        }
        
        @objc func textFieldEditingDidChange(sender: UITextField) {
            
            guard
                let tfPasswordTxtValue = tfPassword.text, !tfPasswordTxtValue.isEmpty,
                let tfConfirmPasswordTextValue = tfConfirmPasswordText.text, !tfConfirmPasswordTextValue.isEmpty
                    
            else {
                disabledButton()
                return
            }
            enableButton()
            
        }

     func disabledButton(){
      btnContinue.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "labelColor")
      btnContinue.isEnabled = false
     }

    func enableButton(){
     btnContinue.isEnabled = true
   }
```

Comment: @Mel,Check and let me know,it works or not

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a test:
Instead of

```
if tfConfirmPasswordText.isEmpty
```

I would have write

```
if tfConfirmPasswordText.isEmpty || tfpasswordText.isEmpty
```